# Checar se String contém virgulas

Tags: lua

```
local t = "Hello, World"
local v = "Hello World"
```

Gostaria de saber como checar se uma string contém virgulas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar a função [find](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial)

```
str = "Hello, World"
if string.find(str, ",") then
  print ("Encontrou virgula.")
else
  print ("Não encontrou virgula.")
end
```

Se o padrão de pesquisa for encontrado a função devolve a posição (inicio e fim), dentro da string, onde ele foi encontrado.

```
> = string.find("Hello Lua user", "Lua")
7       9
> = string.find("Hello Lua user", "banana")
nil
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, não lembrava dessa função string.find! Obrigado